# Error install mysql and mysql-workbench-community for ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, dpkg, mysql, dependencies, mysql-workbench

Since updating to `ubuntu 22.04`, I have faced a lot of problem when installing `mysql` and `mysql-workbench-community`. I kept having dependencies problem, which could not be resolved when installing `mysql`, until I used `aptitude` to install it.
Now I want to install `mysql-workbench-community`. Install via `snap` store is okay but I think there is problem with the app, and some feature is missing. I tried install with `.deb` or `apt` but all failed with dependencies isssue again.

```
quynt@quynt-Nitro-AN515-57:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community_8.0.29-1ubuntu21.10_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-workbench-community.
(Reading database ... 220198 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-workbench-community_8.0.29-1ubuntu21.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community (8.0.29-1ubuntu20.04) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libmysqlclient21 (>= 8.0.11); however:
  Package libmysqlclient21 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libpcrecpp0v5 (>= 7.7); however:
  Package libpcrecpp0v5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libproj15 (>= 6.3.0); however:
  Package libproj15 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2); however:
  Package libpython3.8 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libzip5 (>= 0.10); however:
  Package libzip5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench-community (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-community
```

Comment: @Nmath thank you, I gave up and re-install snap version